# Why is the toolbar not accepting the showAsAction = "always" attribute of the menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 Main2Activity activity = (Main2Activity) getActivity();
 activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 activity.getSupportActionBar();
 final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.action_search);
 toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.seacrh_monan);
 toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
         switch (item.getItemId()){
             case R.id.action_search:
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Bạn đã nhấn nút tìm kiếm",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                     @Override
                     public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                         return false;
                     }

                     @Override
                     public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                         adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                         return false;
                     }
                 });
                 return true;
         }

         return false;
     }
 });
 return view;

}
```

This is my code toolbar in Fragment

And I gave my menu the

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_logout"
 android:title="logout">

</item>
<item
 android:id="@+id/action_search"
 android:title="Search"
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
 app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView|ifRoom"
 app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
 />
```

This is my seacrh_monan.xml

But when I run the application, the toolbar does not get the showAsAction always from the menu. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How many items are there in toolbar menu. Did you try to use `app:showAsAction = "ifRoom"`

Comment: I have 2 items in the menu. I tried to use the app: showAsAction = "ifRoom" but failed.

Comment: update your question with the seacrh_monan.xml file code

Comment: Do you see these two menu items after inflating menu resource in toolbar?

Comment: post complete fragment code

Comment: Two menus are displayed but the showAsAction property is not

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ifRoom` from the attribute `app:showAsAction`. Alternatively, you can also remove the `always` if there are not many items. Note that there's a limit to the number of menu items that will always show as an action.